# Create Tables of different size and columns in PDF

Tags: c#, itext

How to create tables in PDF  with different number of Columns , size using itextSharp in C#.

Table 1)

```
Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4     Column5     Column6
```

Table 2)

```
Col1        Col2        Col3
```

It must look like

```
Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4     Column5     Column6
Col1        Col2        Col3
```

Comment: show the code,what u have tried?????

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
    Document doc        = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    PdfPTable aTable                = new PdfPTable(6);
    aTable.HorizontalAlignment      = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    aTable.WidthPercentage          = 100;
    aTable.AddCell("Column 1");
    aTable.AddCell("Column 2");
    aTable.AddCell("Column 3");
    aTable.AddCell("Column 4");
    aTable.AddCell("Column 5");
    aTable.AddCell("Column 6");

    doc.Add(aTable);

    PdfPTable tp                    = new PdfPTable(3);
    tp.HorizontalAlignment          = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
    tp.WidthPercentage              = 50;
    //tp.SetWidths(new []{60f, 20f, 20f});
    tp.AddCell("Col 1");
    tp.AddCell("Col 2");
    tp.AddCell("Col 3");

    doc.Add(tp);
```